# Animated heatmap of world map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gganimate

I have been making an animated heatmap of world CO2 data between 1850 and 2021, although I have joined the CO2 data and map data and can make an animation my scales are either wrong or off. I want to have a color bar with evenly placed labels: "0", "20", "50", "100", "200", "500", "1000", "2000", "5000", "10000", "20000" on spectrum going from blue to orange. This is my current code:
map_final <- CO2_data_clean3 %>%

```
right_join(world, by= c(mapname = "region")) %>%
ggplot(aes(long, lat, 
         group= group, 
         fill= CO2_emissions)) +
geom_polygon(color = "white", 
           size = 0.5) +
theme_void() +
scale_fill_gradientn(
colors = c(low = "blue", high = "orange"),
values = c(0, 1),
limits = c(0, 1),
breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1),
labels = c("0", "20", "50", "100", "200", "500", "1000", "2000",    "5000", "10000", "20000"),
                 name= "CO2 Emissions (million tons)",
                 guide = guide_colorbar(
                   direction = "horizontal",
                   barheight = unit(20, units = "mm"),
                   barwidth = unit(200, units = "mm"),
                   draw.ulim = FALSE,
                   title.position = "top",
                   title.hjust = 0.5,
                   title.vjust = 0.5 )) +
labs(title="CO2 emissions",
   subtitle = "{current_frame}",
   caption = "Source: OWID_CO2_emissions_data")  +
theme(
plot.title = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5),
plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5),
plot.caption = element_text(size = 8, hjust = 1),
legend.position = "bottom") +
coord_fixed (ratio = 1.3) +
transition_manual(Year)

animate(map_final, 
    fps = 2, 
    height = 700, 
    width = 1000)
```

While this code does provide me with my desired color bar [image: visualisation resulting from current code] it also seems to result countries often being shown in grey (implying lack of data which there is not in the dataset) during the animation. Can anyone help?

Comment: So what do you want to do with countries with no data? Show different colors?